# Overriding the SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer in PrimeFaces to implement a GroupedSelectBoxMenuRenderer

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to override the SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer provided by PrimeFaces to create something like a GroupedSelectCheckboxMenuRenderer. My component needs to have a Grouped select checkbox list like:
Regions select checkbox

**X Asia**

```
X India
X SriLanka
```

**X Europe**

```
X Italy
X Greece
X Germany
```

If somebody selects 'Europe checkbox' then all in Europe list are selected. 
For UI and event handling side what all is required to be done? 
I know that in **faces-config.xml** I need to have the renderer class:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.cswi.codeworx.jsf.GroupedSelectCheckboxMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

and override PrimeFaces org.primefaces.component.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.

Apart from this what all XHTML / Class file changes do I need to do I need to do to have the visual rendering and of the GroupedSelectCheckboxMenuRenderer ? Any pointers to any such existing component would be very welcome.

Comment: (most of) the actual 'rendering' is done in the renderer class, so you need to override that. And for eventhandling override the related JS files. Which ones can be found by analysing the original files.

Comment: Kukeltje, I have had a look at the original component class and files but did not get a clear idea as to how a grouped select 'visual' component can be laid out / rendered. I mean a list can be sent but what do do for a grouped list ? Hence seeking out a more detailed answer poining to perhaps any such similar component implementation.

Comment: Requesting pointers to external references is is not what stackoverflow is about (it is a 'close' reason) ;-). Regarding the 'how to render', well, that is all html. Take your pick... For us trying out what is best takes to much time (it is almost like actually developing the component...) But maybe you can 'abuse' the PrimeFaces tree and use css to style it like you need and override the expanding/collapsing of the nodes. Or look at how the rendering is done there and (re-use) that.

Comment: Oh and did you already see https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml ? It already has grouping. You just need to change some little rendering (add a checkbox) and add some javascript/jquery eventhandling.

Comment: Actually I was looking for something in a multi-select dropdown checkbox. See this link for the Multi component in which I want to it to be grouped multiselect checkbox. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

Comment: Well, now you have hints to sort of similar working components of which you can check the source and use relevant parts in your new component.